# Expressions about making an appointment

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrase-request, expressions, phrasal-verbs

- I want to say that I will make an appointment for client

**How can I say it *(besides “I'll make an appointment for you")*?**

1) I'll ***sign*** you ***in*** for appointment (on Saturday)

2) I'll ***take*** you on Saturday

3) I'll ***take*** you ***in*** on Saturday

Comment: It’s “sign you **up**”, not “sign you **in**”. You’d sign someone _in_ after they arrived.

Answer (score 3):

You can also say

> I will **put you down for** Saturday.

The object of **for** in **put me down for** can be a time-slot:

> Put me down for 3PM.

or anything to which you are making a commitment, such as an order:

> Put me down for three boxes of Samoas (Girl-Scout cookies).

or a pledge, whether of money

> Put me down for $50.

or of time and effort:

> Put me down for the welcome booth (that is, to man it).

Answer (score 1):

You

> sign *someone* **up**

for an appointment, by

> signing them **on to** a list of appointments, or
>   putting them **into** a diary of appointments

and then

> sign them **in**

when they show up for the appointment, and possibly

> sign them **out**

when they leave.